# List plot DataRange doesn't work

Tags: plotting, syntax

I have a set of coordinates for 0.4 < x < 5.6 and -10 < y < -4. When I use ListPlot, it plots the data in the ranges 0 < x < 5.6 and -10 < y < 0:
[image]

I tried to use `DataRange -> {{0.4, 5.6},{-10, -4}}`, but this doesn't change anything. Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Here is the code for the plot

```
ListPlot[{A, B}, 
 Filling -> Automatic, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 3/4, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[22, Black], 
 FrameLabel -> {"Scalar mass [GeV]", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Log\), \(10\)]\)[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)]"},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[Style[#, 
      21] & /@ {"A", 
     "B"}, {0.75, 
    0.75}], GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.6]}, {Opacity[1]}}, 
 DataRange -> {{0.5, 5.6},{-10, -4}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], 
 Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Without knowing what form `A` and `B` take, it's hard to reproduce the results and figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JasonB. : is it enough to show a picture? The data for A and B corresponds to the contours on the plot I've inserted in my question.

Comment: @JasonB. : even considering simple example


Table1 = Table[{x, Exp[-x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Table1, DataRange ->{{0.1, 5.2}, {0, 0.6}}]
I can't make DataRange work correctly.

Comment: Right - but it isn't clear what form the lists take.  Are `A` and `B` of the form $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots\}$ or $\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},\ldots\}$?  It's easiest to help if we can copy/paste/run the code

Comment: Try changing `DataRange ->{{0.1, 5.2}, {0, 0.6}}` to `PlotRange ->{{0.1, 5.2}, {0, 0.6}}`.  Does that give the plot you were expecting?

Comment: @JohnTaylor I suspect that `DataRange` is simply ignored in your simple example if you provide your data already as *pairs of* $(x,y)$ values. `DataRange` is for cases in which one of the coordinates (typically the abscissa) is not present in your data.

Comment: @JasonB.: thank you, this helps!